# CSS animations - the current "left" expressed in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am new to CSS animations and I am trying to hide a component on the right side of the display. I have an React component with `width: window.innerWidth - 60` style. This is set with JavaScript (obviously). -60 because part of the component should be visible and when this part is clicked, I want to slide the component to left to show the whole component. The problem is, that i do not know how to set the animation parameters since i need to say:"from the values you have +200px".

```
@-webkit-keyframes showonrightaside {
    from {
      left: currentValue;
    }
    to {
      left: currentValue + 200px;
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to express that it should start from the current value and increment the `left` property. Is this even possible or do i have to do some JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible, because CSS is _not_ a programming language... It's a pity.

Comment: But it gets possible in some cases if you use tricks, for example use margins (animate from margin 0 to margin -200).

Comment: You could use JavaScript to toggle a class that holds the CSS transitions you want to perform on your DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5q5bzh9/) to elaborate somewhat more on my previous comment.
It uses the translate property:

```
transform:translateX(200px);
```

---

To ensure that it works in as many browsers as possible and is also future-proof, use the vendor prefixes:

```
-webkit-transform:translateX(200px); // chrome and safari
-moz-transform:translateX(200px); // mozilla firefox
-ms-transform:translateX(200px); // internet explorer
-o-transform:translateX(200px); // opera
transform:translateX(200px); // regular
```